# SQL Server not allowing me to create an Application Pool Identity Login

Tags: iis-8.5, sql-server-2014-express

I know this kind of issue has been raised many times before and I have read through a dozen or more articles on trying to get this to work but am getting nowhere.  Hopefully this question will lead to a result not clearly identifed in other articles.

I have a new Windows 2012 R2 server running IIS 8.5.  I've also installed SQL Server 2014 Express (default instance) and created an empty database called `ActivbaseLive`.

I've created a classic ASP application under an Application Pool called "`activbase`".
In SSMS I go to Security (server level) > Logins > New Login and enter a Login name of "`IIS_AppPool\activbase`" (Windows authentication; everything else default) and SSMS comes straight back at me with "

> Create failed for Login 'IIS_APPPOOL\activbase'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)"

and under additional information:

> "Windows NT user or group 'IIS_APPPOOL\activbase' not found.  Check the name again. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15401)"

Other points:

1. I've checked the application pool name for any stupid typos but it
   checks out.
2. ASP is an enabled feature and a simple ASP test program shows that Classic ASP is working okay
3. Originally I had called my application pool '`activbase.net`' and I was able to create the Login at SQL Server and database level but after getting "Cannot open database "ActivbaseLive" requested by the login"
4. I have also tried adding the database I am trying to target (`ActivbaseLive`) under New Login... > User Mappings but this doesn't help.
5. I am aware that Virtual Accounts like Application Pool Identities do not show up in the Search Box.
6. I have tried doing this via T-SQL but I get the same error:

   ```
   USE [master]
   GO
   CREATE LOGIN [IIS_APPPOOL\activbase] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
   GO

   Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
   Windows NT user or group 'IIS_APPPOOL\activbase' not found. Check the name again.
   ```

Any ideas or anything else I can provide?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the underscore in `IIS_APPPOOL`. Change that to a space and it should work.

Comment: How could I be so stupid!  Why did I not pick up on that.  I was focused on the username, not the domain part!  Doh!